# br:last-child not working when an element is after the br

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am hiding `br` tags in my html on mobile, but would like just the last `br` tag to function normally. This seems to work unless the element after the last `br` is an anchor tag.

I'm using the following code:

```css
p br {
  display: none;
}
p br:last-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>lorem
  <br>loremlorem lorem
  <br>
  <br>READ ARTICLE IN JOURNAL</p>
<p>lorem
  <br>loremlorem lorem
  <br>
  <br>
  <a href="#">READ ARTICLE IN JOURNAL</a>
</p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5j8dtwfd/2/

The css works as expected with the last `br` tag having `display:block` applied to it.

However, if I wrap the "read article.." text in an anchor the css stops being able to find the last `br`.

I'm not sure what's happening here to cause this, is this the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

:last-child means the last element in a container.  Therefore if the br isn't the last child of the container br:last-child wouldn't work (the a tag is the last child)

What you want is br:last-of-type (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Alast-of-type)

Answer (score 8):

With `last-child`, you're targeting the last sibling, not necessarily the last `br`. In this case, the last sibling is the anchor element. Instead, use `last-of-type`.

```css
p br {
  display: none;
}
p br:last-of-type {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>lorem
  <br>loremlorem lorem
  <br>
  <br>READ ARTICLE IN JOURNAL
</p>
<p>lorem
  <br>loremlorem lorem
  <br>
  <br><a href="#">READ ARTICLE IN JOURNAL</a>
</p>
```

Note that in your code, the CSS applies `display: block` to `p br:last-child`.

Since the last child is blockified, shouldn't the anchor break to a new line anyway?

Not in this case, because the rule applies only if `br` is the last child.

So, in sort of a circular fashion, your CSS is targeting the last child, but only if it's a `br`, and that's not the case, so nothing happens. The actual last child is an anchor element, but there's nothing targeting it in your CSS.

If you remove the `br` from the selector in the original code, it will break the anchor to a new line.

```css
p br {
  display: none;
}
p :last-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>lorem
  <br>loremlorem lorem
  <br>
  <br>READ ARTICLE IN JOURNAL
</p>
<p>lorem
  <br>loremlorem lorem
  <br>
  <br>
  <a href="#">READ ARTICLE IN JOURNAL</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

try using `p:last-of-type` instead of `p:last-child`

Answer (score 2):

Your working example only works because a text node does not count as a child, so the br is being counted as last child. In your second example,  the anchor is the last child. If you want to always target the last br no matter what comes after,  what you should use is :last-of-type, not :last-child.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "read article.." text to next line, you can try

```
p a:last-child{
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately in my project, the anchor tag is an inline-block that's styled to look like a button and it's used in multiple spots with varying content widths. Making it display:block would make it 100% of its container width or I'd have to set an exact width which wouldn't be ideal. I'll use :last-of-type to get it working the way I'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
p  br{
  display: none;
}

p  br:last-of-type {
  display: block;
}
```

It's totally work well.

Comment: "Try this, It's totally work well." doesn't seem like a very compelling answer to me. I'd be wary of it.

Comment: I just want help! I'm Vietnamese so my English expression not good.

Answer (score 0):

`<br>` is not a block level element. This just breaks line and this holds no any `height` or `width`. So what you can do is make that anchor tag block.

```
p  br:not(:last-child) {
  display: none;
}

p a {
  display: block;
}
```

or you can use `:last-of-type`

```
p  br:not(:last-child) {
  display: none;
}

p br:last-of-type {
  display: block;
}
```

This also works because `:last-of-type`: it targets a particular type of element in a particular arrangement with relation to similar siblings, not all siblings.

Please visit this link for more information:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/last-of-type/

Comment: "<br> is not a block level element." Well, it can be, depending on the browser.

Comment: :last-of-type was the solution here. The anchor in the live html was styled like a button in multiple places and couldn't be 100% width or have a fixed width so it needed to stay inline-block.